# CakePHP response numbers as strings

Tags: cakephp

CakePHP is serializing number as string in json response, like this {"foo": "123"}, It should be  {"foo": 123 } there are any configuration?

```
    $stm = "select * from clients";
    $response = $conn->execute($stm)->fetchAll('assoc');

    $this->set([
        'success' => $success,
        'code' => $code,
        'response' => $response,
        'errors' => $errors,
        '_serialize' => ['success', 'code', 'response', 'errors'],
    ]);
```

Comment: please check your  database, its varchar or int

Comment: and use $this->Clients->find('all')  // using model

Comment: @RiteshParyali using model it works fine, but we have some complex custom query that we need to use fetchAll('assoc')! In the database is int! 
If I use this function json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK), it works, but probable there are some configurations in cake to do this in _serialize!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can pass json_encode options like this

```
$this->set('_jsonOptions', JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
$this->set('_serialize', ['success', 'code', 'response', 'errors']);
```

https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#creating-json-views